# UITextFields not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitextfield

I'm creating a registration view that has 14 `UITextFields`.  All of them are set to `userInteractionEnabled` and the delegate is set to "File's Owner". The first 8 text fields will enable when touched.  The following 6, however, will not respond to touch. I'm basically just throwing this out there to see if any other iOS developers have run into any issue like this. In the View Controller, I only have code to validate the email field using a regular expression when the "Submit" button is touched. As well as code to set the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`. I'll post the entire `.m` below.

```
#import "RegistrationViewController.h"

@implementation RegistrationViewController

@synthesize scrollView, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtAge, txtGender, txtAddress1, txtAddress2, txtCity, txtState, txtCountry, txtPostal, txtEmail, txtPhone, txtAccount, txtCgAcct;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1044);

[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) validateData {

NSString *regEmail = txtEmail.text;
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b" options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:regEmail options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [regEmail length])];

}

-(void) postRegData {



}

-(IBAction)submitReg:(id)sender{
[self validateData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you have a view over the top of the bottom 6 by mistake that's intercepting the touch events maybe?

Comment: No sir.  The hierarchy goes as follows: ScrollView(topmost)->View->Objects(Labels, TextFields, TextViews, Buttons). There's nothing else on the view. 16 labels, 14 TextFields, 2 TextViews, 2 Buttons.

Comment: Strange then. There's no reason why you'd be seeing it if they are all identically set up. Can you post a link to download the XIB and VC .h/.m maybe?

Comment: ive seen this happen if the textfields themselves are not within the frame of its parent. try changing the scrollview background colour to something obvious and see if the textfields are actually within the frame correctly

Comment: Link to my github repo: [https://github.com/tallybear/PA](https://github.com/tallybear/PA)

Comment: I changed the color of the scrollView, but you can't see the color change because there is another view within it.  I changed the color of the view that actually contains the objects, and they are all within the bounds of the view. The scrollView is my TOPMOST view.  Then within that is a view.  Then within THAT view are my objects.

Comment: I just completely rebuilt the view from scratch, and it's still doing the same thing. This is completely ridiculous.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this if anyone has any ideas.  I noticed yesterday that the buttons on the bottom of the view aren't working either.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the solution - but was sort of like a bug - you can remove the view which is under the scrollview and have all elements in the scrollview itself, then all work well. Main problem was w.r.t heirarchy - scrollview=>view=>textview and the view's height was not changeable, so the issue of not able to select any content as they were going outside the view - u can check this by setting background color to that view.

If you need the properties of the view or with same heirarachy , then first create a main view, then scroll view of that main view's size and the child views of same size and then work on them(you can increase height of view, add textfields below and then bring back size to normal value - 460)

Comment: You have saved my day and night. Oh, finally. I have spent way too much time here to debug this. As I am new to constraints, ios programming, I was struggling to find a solution. I was about to ask a new question and I found this one. thanks.